# Modify tick label text

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

I want to make some modifications to a few selected tick labels in a plot.

For example, if I do:

```
label = axes.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[2].label
label.set_fontsize(size)
label.set_rotation('vertical')
```

the font size and the orientation of the tick label is changed.

However, if try:

```
label.set_text('Foo')
```

the tick label is *not* modified. Also if I do:

```
print label.get_text()
```

nothing is printed.

Here's some more strangeness. When I tried this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

axes = plt.figure().add_subplot(111)
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
axes.plot(t, s)
for ticklabel in axes.get_xticklabels():
    print(ticklabel.get_text())
```

Only empty strings are printed, but the plot contains ticks labeled as '0.0', '0.5', '1.0', '1.5', and '2.0'.

[image]

Comment: Options also apply to [seaborn axes-level plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots).

Answer (score 415, accepted):

Caveat: Unless the ticklabels are already set to a string (as is usually the case in e.g. a boxplot), this will not work with any version of matplotlib newer than `1.1.0`.  If you're working from the current github master, this won't work.  I'm not sure what the problem is yet...  It may be an unintended change, or it may not be...

Normally, you'd do something along these lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# We need to draw the canvas, otherwise the labels won't be positioned and 
# won't have values yet.
fig.canvas.draw()

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]
labels[1] = 'Testing'

ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

To understand the reason why you need to jump through so many hoops, you need to understand a bit more about how matplotlib is structured.

Matplotlib deliberately avoids doing "static" positioning of ticks, etc, unless it's explicitly told to.  The assumption is that you'll want to interact with the plot, and so the bounds of the plot, ticks, ticklabels, etc will be dynamically changing.

Therefore, you can't just set the text of a given tick label.  By default, it's re-set by the axis's Locator and Formatter every time the plot is drawn.

However, if the Locators and Formatters are set to be static (`FixedLocator` and `FixedFormatter`, respectively), then the tick labels stay the same.

This is what `set_*ticklabels` or `ax.*axis.set_ticklabels` does.

Hopefully that makes it slighly more clear as to why changing an individual tick label is a bit convoluted.

Often, what you actually want to do is just annotate a certain position.  In that case, look into `annotate`, instead.

Comment: this does not appear to work with the current version (1.20)!

Comment: If the ticklabels are already set to a string as in e.g. a boxplot, this is still working. This might be obvious, but since the first line of the answer is that it is not working on newer matplotlib versions, users might skip it completely (I did initially). Maybe mention this briefly.

Comment: i think you can condense it down to *plt.gca().set_xticklabels(labels)*

Comment: what if I wanna the fontweight of "testing" to be `bold` while others use fontweight of "light". Is there a way to do it?

Comment: for those using this in a jupyter notebook may benefit from noting that `fig.canvas.draw()` is crucial

Comment: You can use `item._text` instead of `item.get_text()`, it also works with non-text labels!

Answer (score 167):

One can also do this with *pylab* and *xticks*

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,1,2]
y = [90,40,65]
labels = ['high', 'low', 37337]
plt.plot(x,y, 'r')
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

Answer (score 120):

In newer versions of `matplotlib`, if you do not set the tick labels with a bunch of `str` values, they are `''` by default (and when the plot is draw the labels are simply the ticks values). Knowing that, to get your desired output would require something like this:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> axes = figure().add_subplot(111)
>>> a=axes.get_xticks().tolist()
>>> a[1]='change'
>>> axes.set_xticklabels(a)
[<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x539aa50>, <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x53a0c90>, 
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x53a73d0>, <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x53a7a50>, 
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x53aa110>, <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x53aa790>]
>>> plt.show()
```

and the result:
[image]

and now if you check the `_xticklabels`, they are no longer a bunch of `''`.

```
>>> [item.get_text() for item in axes.get_xticklabels()]
['0.0', 'change', '1.0', '1.5', '2.0']
```

It works in the versions from `1.1.1rc1` to the current version `2.0`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Cleanest solution IMO; just supply `set_xticklabels` with a mixed list of strings and tick objects.

Comment: Be aware that if the tick labels are set as ints, this will change them to floats. Easily worked around but worth noting.

Comment: This one worked (`ax.get_xticks().tolist()`). The most voted solution did not (`ax.get_xtickslabels()`). Somehow it was not able to extract the labels before the `plt.show()` was excuted, although I used `fig.canvas.draw()` as suggested.

Comment: FYI, from modern [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related): "pylab is deprecated and its use is strongly discouraged because of namespace pollution. Use pyplot instead."

Comment: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator

Comment: @baxx The solution to this is found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723514/userwarning-fixedformatter-should-only-be-used-together-with-fixedlocator

Answer (score 30):

It's been a while since this question was asked. As of today (`matplotlib 2.2.2`) and after some reading and trials, I think the best/proper way is the following:

Matplotlib has a module named [`ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) that *"contains classes to support completely configurable tick locating and formatting"*. To modify a specific tick from the plot, the following works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np 

def update_ticks(x, pos):
    if x == 0:
        return 'Mean'
    elif pos == 6:
        return 'pos is 6'
    else:
        return x

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=25, edgecolor='black')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(update_ticks))
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram with random values from a normal distribution]

**Caveat!** `x` is the value of the tick and `pos` is its relative position in order in the axis. Notice that `pos` takes values starting in `1`, not in `0` as usual when indexing.

---

In my case, I was trying to format the `y-axis` of a histogram with percentage values. `mticker` has another class named `PercentFormatter` that can do this easily without the need to define a separate function as before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np 

data = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
weights = np.ones_like(data) / len(data)
ax.hist(data, bins=25, weights=weights, edgecolor='black')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0, decimals=1))
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram with random values from a normal distribution]

In this case `xmax` is the data value that corresponds to 100%. Percentages are computed as `x / xmax * 100`, that's why we fix `xmax=1.0`. Also, `decimals` is the number of decimal places to place after the point.

Answer (score 23):

This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

x1 = [0,1,2,3]
squad = ['Fultz','Embiid','Dario','Simmons']

ax1.set_xticks(x1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(squad, minor=False, rotation=45)
```

[image: FEDS]

Answer (score 15):

The axes class has a [set_yticklabels](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels) function which allows you to set the tick labels, like so:

```
#ax is the axes instance
group_labels = ['control', 'cold treatment',
             'hot treatment', 'another treatment',
             'the last one']

ax.set_xticklabels(group_labels)
```

I'm still working on why your example above didn't work.

Comment: But I only want to alter a single label. The above trick requires that you extract all tick labels and set the desired one to a new value. But how can I extract the tick labels when label.get_text() returns nothing?

Answer (score 10):

This also works in matplotlib 3:

```
x1 = [0,1,2,3]
squad = ['Fultz','Embiid','Dario','Simmons']

plt.xticks(x1, squad, rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you do not work with `fig` and `ax` and you want to modify all labels (e.g. for normalization) you can do this:

```
labels, locations = plt.yticks()
plt.yticks(labels, labels/max(labels))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we are intending to modify some of the tick labels in `Matplotlib` but with no side effects, which works clean and which preserves offset scientific notations. None of the issues discussed in some of the other answers are faced in this solution.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.formatter.use_mathtext'] = True

class CustomScalarFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, useOffset=None, useMathText=None, useLocale=None, replace_values=([],[])):
        super().__init__(useOffset=None, useMathText=None, useLocale=None)
        self.replace_values = replace_values

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        """
        Return the format for tick value *x* at position *pos*.
        """
        if len(self.locs) == 0:
            return ''
        elif x in self.replace_values[0]:
            idx = self.replace_values[0].index(x)
            return str(self.replace_values[1][idx])
        else:
            xp = (x - self.offset) / (10. ** self.orderOfMagnitude)
            if abs(xp) < 1e-8:
                xp = 0
            return self._format_maybe_minus_and_locale(self.format, xp)


z = np.linspace(0, 5000, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xmajorformatter = CustomScalarFormatter(replace_values=([2000,0],['$x_0$','']))
ymajorformatter = CustomScalarFormatter(replace_values=([1E7,0],['$y_0$','']))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xmajorformatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ymajorformatter)

ax.plot(z,z**2)
plt.show()
```

What we have done here is we created a derivative class of `matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter` class which matplotlib uses by default to format the labels. The code is copied from matplotlib source but only `__call__` function is copied and modified in it. Following

```
        elif x in self.replace_values[0]:
            idx = self.replace_values[0].index(x)
            return str(self.replace_values[1][idx])
```

are the new lines added to the `__call__` function which do the replacement job. The advantage of a derived class is that it inherits all the features from the base class like offset notation, scientific notation labels if values are large. The result is:

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: This is a nice solution, but does it work with non-frame situations, where the axis might be in the middle (or even on the right) of the diagram?  See e.g. https://github.com/sagemath/sage/pull/37502#issuecomment-1972256042 (where we gratefully acknowledge your contribution!) - hopefully an easy extension for the somewhat unique use cases in that package exists.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
  fig,axis = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(13,6),sharex=True)
  axis.set_xticklabels(['0', 'testing', '10000', '20000', '30000'],fontsize=22)
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that all the solutions posted here that use `set_xticklabels()` are not preserving the **offset**, which is a scaling factor applied to the ticks values to create better-looking tick labels. For instance, if the ticks are on the order of 0.00001 (1e-5), matplotlib will automatically add a scaling factor (or `offset`) of `1e-5`, so the resultant tick labels may end up as `1 2 3 4`, rather than `1e-5 2e-5 3e-5 4e-5`.

Below gives an example:

The `x` array is `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])/1e6`, and `y` is `y=x**2`. So both are very small values.

**Left column**: manually change the 1st and 3rd labels, as suggested by @Joe Kington. Note that the offset is lost.

**Mid column**: similar as @iipr suggested, using a `FuncFormatter`.

**Right column**: My suggested offset-preserving solution.

Figure here:
[image]

Complete code here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some *small* data to plot
x = np.arange(5)/1e6
y = x**2

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,6))

#------------------The set_xticklabels() solution------------------
ax1 = axes[0]
ax1.plot(x, y)
fig.canvas.draw()
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax1.get_xticklabels()]

# Modify specific labels
labels[1] = 'Testing'
labels[3] = 'Testing2'
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax1.set_title('set_xticklabels()')

#--------------FuncFormatter solution--------------
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

def update_ticks(x, pos):
    if pos==1:
        return 'testing'
    elif pos==3:
        return 'testing2'
    else:
        return x

ax2=axes[1]
ax2.plot(x,y)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(update_ticks))
ax2.set_title('Func Formatter')

#-------------------My solution-------------------
def changeLabels(axis, pos, newlabels):
    '''Change specific x/y tick labels

    Args:
        axis (Axis): .xaxis or .yaxis obj.
        pos (list): indices for labels to change.
        newlabels (list): new labels corresponding to indices in <pos>.
    '''

    if len(pos) != len(newlabels):
        raise Exception("Length of <pos> doesn't equal that of <newlabels>.")

    ticks = axis.get_majorticklocs()
    # get the default tick formatter
    formatter = axis.get_major_formatter()
    # format the ticks into strings
    labels = formatter.format_ticks(ticks)

    # Modify specific labels
    for pii, lii in zip(pos, newlabels):
        labels[pii] = lii

    # Update the ticks and ticklabels. Order is important here.
    # Need to first get the offset (1e-6 in this case):
    offset = formatter.get_offset()
    # Then set the modified labels:
    axis.set_ticklabels(labels)
    # In doing so, matplotlib creates a new FixedFormatter and sets it to the xaxis
    # and the new FixedFormatter has no offset. So we need to query the
    # formatter again and re-assign the offset:
    axis.get_major_formatter().set_offset_string(offset)

    return

ax3 = axes[2]
ax3.plot(x, y)

changeLabels(ax3.xaxis, [1, 3], ['Testing', 'Testing2'])
ax3.set_title('With offset')

fig.show()
plt.savefig('tick_labels.png')
```

**Caveat**: it appears that solutions that use `set_xticklabels()`, including my own, relies on `FixedFormatter`, which is static and doesn't respond to figure resizing. To observe the effect, change the figure to a smaller size, e.g. `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(6,6))` and enlarge the figure window. You will notice that that only the mid column responds to resizing and adds more ticks as the figure gets larger. The left and right column will have empty tick labels (see figure below).

**Caveat 2**: I also noticed that if your tick values are floats, calling `set_xticklabels(ticks)` directly might give you ugly-looking strings, like `1.499999999998` instead of `1.5`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html), or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) for the y-axis, can be used to change the ticks **and labels** [beginning with `matplotlib 3.5.0`](https://matplotlib.org/3.6.0/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.5.0.html#settings-tick-positions-and-labels-simultaneously-in-set-ticks). These are for the object oriented interface.

  - If using the *[`pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/pyplot_summary.html) state-based interface*, use [`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) or [`plt.yticks`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html), as shown in other answers.
  - In general terms, pass a `list` / `array` of numbers to the `ticks` parameter, and a `list` / `array` strings to the `labels` parameter.
- In this case, the x-axis is comprised of continuous numeric values, so there are no set **Text** labels, as thoroughly explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/7758804). This is not the case when plots have discrete ticks (e.g. boxplot, barplot).

  - `[Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, '')]` is returned by [`ax.get_xticklabels()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html)
  - `[-0.25  0.    0.25  0.5   0.75  1.    1.25  1.5   1.75  2.    2.25]` is returned by [`ax.get_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html)

    - `type(ax.get_xticks())` is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`
    - `type(ax.get_xticks()[0])` is `<class 'numpy.float64'>`
- Since the OP is trying to replace a numeric **label** with a `str`, all of the values in the `ndarray` must be converted to `str` type, and the value to be changed can be updated.
- **Tested in `python 3.10` and `matplotlib 3.5.2`**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# plot data
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

# plot
ax.plot(t, s)

# get the xticks, which are the numeric location of the ticks
xticks = ax.get_xticks()

# get the xticks and convert the values in the array to str type
xticklabels = list(map(str, ax.get_xticks()))

# update the string to be changed
xticklabels[1] = 'Test'

# set the xticks and the labels
_ = ax.set_xticks(xticks, xticklabels)
```

[image]

- Note the x-axis offset is not preserved when changing the xticklabels. However, the correct value is shown without the offset.

```py
# create figure and axes
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 6), sharex=False)

# plot data
t = np.linspace(0, 1500000, 100)
s = t**2

# plot
ax1.plot(t, s)
ax2.plot(t, s)

# get the xticks, which are the numeric location of the ticks
xticks = ax2.get_xticks()

# get the xticks and convert the values in the array to str type
xticklabels = list(map(str, ax2.get_xticks()))

# update the string to be changed
xticklabels[1] = 'Test'

# set the xticks and the labels
_ = ax2.set_xticks(xticks, xticklabels, rotation=90)
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

you can do:

```
for k in ax.get_xmajorticklabels():
    if some-condition:
        k.set_color(any_colour_you_like)

draw()
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer is so heavily downvoted?

Comment: @HlynurDavíðHlynsson I think it has not really something to do with the question. Well, maybe with some editing... Please edit it, if you get to relate it to the question. ;)