# Change color of cbar legend text python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to change the text color of the cbar legend values ? We want to use a black background but the text is falling away. We use Matplotlib for plotting.
We can change the text color of the label, but not of the values.

```
 cbar = m.colorbar(cs,location='right',pad="10%")
 cbar.set_label('dBZ', color="white")
```

Thank you in advanced.

Kevin Broeren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color of the color bar values using set_yticklabels since they are tick labels for the color bar axis. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn

# plot something
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax = ax.imshow(randn(100,100))

# create the color bar
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
cbar.set_label('dBZ', color = "white")

# update the text 
t = cbar.ax.get_yticklabels();
labels = [item.get_text() for item in t]
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(labels, color = 'white')
plt.show()
```

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/matplotlib-modify-tick-label-text) has an explanation of why you need to do it this way.

[image: color bar with white text for the label and values]