# plotting pandas intraday time series only for periods with data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series of intraday measurements. measurements are only taken during daytime on weekdays. when I plot the data, pandas extends the xaxis over the full time horizont, so the plot shows data gaps

```
dfb.loc[:,("value", "exp_1")].plot()
```

[image]

I can tell pandas/matplotlib to ignore the index and the plot is fine, but I would like to present the dates on the x axis

```
    dfb.loc[:,("value", "exp_1")].plot(ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

I also tried to define the xticks with my index, but that leads to teh first chart with a cluttered x axis description

```
    dfb.loc[:,("value", "exp_1")].plot(xticks=dfb.index)
```

[image]

Is there a way to get a plot like the 2nd plot while keeping the dates?

EDIT:
Here is a subset of the data and the plot

[image]

Comment: @chrise ever figured this out?

Answer (score 4):

It looks a bit like a bug. You may also consider creating an issue on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/

When I tried it with a DatetimeIndex with frequency set to days or business days then the x axis isn't affected. But if the frequency is finer (e.g. hours, business hours), then the axis does get extended - exactly as in your case.

A workaround (not sure if the best possible) would be to convert the index of the data frame to strings. Either setting it directly:

```
df.index = df.index.astype('str')
```

or maybe better changing only for printing:

```
df.set_index(df.index.astype('str')).plot(rot=30)
```

The argument `rot=30` is optional, but without it the labels get cluttered.

Comment: if i set them as string then that loses a lot of information and the xticks become a mess as it tries to present every single one

Answer (score 0):

plt.xticks(x,labels) seems to work but is super slow for large dataset..
Here are the links for something similar to this problem:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440179
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

Comment: AFAIK, the OP was asking how to get rid of the gaps when plotting timestamps, not how to rotate tick labels.