# Matplotlib, make intervals from data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Below is the screenshot from my dataset. [image]

I am plotting, length of the text ( it varies from 1 to 1000)  along the x axis , and sum(useful), sum(funny) and sum(cool), along the y axis.

I am using below command to plot:

```
df.plot(x="length(text)", y=["sum(useful)", "sum(funny)", "sum(cool)"], kind="bar",figsize=None)
```

Below is the screenshot from my plot:
[image]

Now, I want to make my x axis, in intervals, rather than continuous values in graph, to make it more visible. How to achieve this in matplotlib ?

Comment: have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813601/how-to-set-x-axis-values-in-matplotlib-python

Comment: In the future, it's also more useful to post your data in a code section using `df.head().to_clipboard()` and I wouldn't blur out parts of the figure. That's probably useful in seeing what the problem is, in this case what DavidG pointed out

Comment: @DavidG:Values for the length(text) are integers. Thats what, I am plotting in X axis. Since they are ranging from 1 to 1000, it makes x axis, blurred. Which is the reason I wanted to take intervals along X axis.

Comment: @skoundin Actually, you're right. I've removed the duplicate vote.