# Seaborn renaming ticks in a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been dealing with this detail for some time now, and there must be a simple solution to this. I am trying to plot a seaborn heatmap, i.e.
where a is some matrix.

```
g=sns.heatmap(a).
```

This works fine, yet I do not want x and y labels at all, I just wish to mark specific values, e.g. x ticks:

```
    for label in g.ax_heatmap.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
        if label.get_text() in to_mark:
            label.set_size(10)
            label.set_weight("bold")
            label.set_color("red")
            label.set_text("I do not work")
```

The problem occurs at the last line, where I try to rename the labels from current longer namest to just "*", for example. My question is, why does label.set_text("*") not do the job? And what are possible alternatives.

Thank you!

EDIT:

"working" example

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(midframe)
cmap1 = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True, rot=-.3, light=1)
g = sns.clustermap(a,cmap=cmap1,xticklabels=True,yticklabels=False)
top = [str(x) for x in range(0,10)]
for label in g.ax_heatmap.xaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    if label.get_text() in top:
        label.set_size(10)
        label.set_weight("bold")
        label.set_color("red")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example

Comment: I think this is connected with the nature of Text object, not really the example itself, but I still provide current code.

Comment: Look for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text

Comment: @sdgawerzswer the code is still not complete. If you provide the complete cod, I can run and find what is going on. You can ofcourse pass dummy data.

Comment: @pcu , thanks! this seems to be the matplotlib problem! You can submit this as an answer or I close the question..