# Changing alpha value of ticklabels without specifying text

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, alpha

Matplotlib allows changing the alpha value of almost anything, but how does it work for an ticklabel?
If I have a text, it is easy:

```
ax.set_xticklabel(labels, alpha=alpha)
```

The case is different if I do not have a text as the following throws a TypeError, due to missing labels.

```
ax.set_xticklabel(alpha=alpha)
```

Therefore, my next idea was to get the automatically generated ticklabels and use them to do the job:

```
labels = [label.get_text() for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, alpha=alpha
```

The problem here is, the labels are empty due to the dynamic nature of matplotlib (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text)).

So, is there an easy way to change the alpha of my ticklabels without knowing the text beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not desirable to set the ticklabels themselves, if you want to change their color. The reason is that setting the labels via `ax.set_ticklabels` changes the formatter to a `FixedFormatter`; with this one would loose the automatic formatting behaviour.

Instead change the alpha of the text objects that later constitute the ticklabels. To this end `plt.setp` is a useful feature.

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), alpha=0.3)
```

The same can be achieved via

```
for t in ax.get_xticklabels():
    t.set_alpha(0.3)
```