# Matplotlib bar chart for negative numbers going above x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a bar chart of negative values where the baseline x-axis is at -10 instead of 0 and the values, because they are all `-10<x<0`, extend up from the baseline.

If I plot it as is, the bars extend downward:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vals = [-4, -6, -8, -6, -5]
plt.bar(range(len(vals)), vals)
```

[image]

I could fake it in some sense by adding 10 to the data, but then I would have to remove the y-tick values, and I need to keep them.

```
new_vals = [val + 10 for val in vals]
plt.yticks([])
plt.bar(range(len(new_vals)), new_vals)
```

[image]

So how can I make the second image with the y-ticks of the first image and, preferably, without "faking" any of the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/8033585 shows how to achieve this. Instead of adding 10, consider changing sign of data. Get the labels and then change their sign.

Comment: Using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and `ax.set_yticklabels(range(-10, 0))` per your link solved it for me, although I still have to fake the data. Also, had I just flipped the sign it would change the shape of the graph, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: This is not "faking data": you really just want to plot `data - (-10)` i.e. `data + 10`. That's how shifting your baseline works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html example, you can also do like this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
def neg_tick(x, pos):
    return '%.1f' % (-x if x else 0) # avoid negative zero (-0.0) labels

formatter = FuncFormatter(neg_tick)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.bar(range(len(vals)), [-v for v in vals]) # or -numpy.asarray(vals)
# or, let Python enumerate bars:
# plt.bar(*zip(*enumerate(-v for v in vals)))
plt.show()
```

You cannot not "fake" data. Bar charts plot bars up for positive data and down for negative. If you want things differently, you need to trick bar chart somehow.

[image]

IMO, the above solution is better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/8033585 because it does not need the trick with drawing canvas, changing labels, etc.

---

If you do want to have "reverted" bar length (as it is in your example), then you can do the following:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import numpy as np

# shifted up:
vals = np.asarray(vals)
minval = np.amin(vals)
minval += np.sign(minval) # "add" 1 so that "lowest" bar is still drawn
def neg_tick(x, pos):
    return '%.1f' % (x + minval if x != minval else 0)

formatter = FuncFormatter(neg_tick)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.bar(*zip(*enumerate(-minval + vals)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis.html)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
vals = [-4, -6, -8, -6, -5]
plt.bar(range(len(vals)), vals)
```

[image]

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.bar(range(len(vals)), vals)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: This changes the shape of the data, which isn't what I'm looking for. But otherwise, this is a good solution.