# Matplotlib xticks labels: how to modify attributes value

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Following [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) I know that I can extract the xticks labels and positions using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
locs, labels=plt.xticks()
```

the new variable `labels` is a `matplotlib.cbook.silent_list`, which
doesn't behave like a normal list.
Is there a way to access and modify any attribute value of the `labels` elements?
Specifically I would like to know if I can select a subset of the labels (i.e. slice the silent_list) and modify a particular attribute for that subset.

Here is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y=np.random.normal(0, 1, (8, 1))
plt.scatter(x, y)
locs, labels=plt.xticks()
```

As an example, let say I want to change the labels color to red for all but the first and last element of `labels`; if I open one of the elements of the variable I can see that there is the attribute `_color` with value `k`, which I would like to change in `r`:

[image: here]

I tried to slice it:

```
labels[1:-1]
```

But it returns:

```
Out[]: [Text(2,0,'2'), Text(4,0,'4'), Text(6,0,'6'), Text(8,0,'8')]
```

and this is as far as I managed to go.
I couldn't figure out a way to access the attribute and change its value.

**NB**: I am looking for a general way to access these attributes and change the value, I do not care about changing the labels color specifically. That's just an example.

Comment: `plt.setp(labels[2:-2], color="red")` (note the 2 because one label is outside of the axes)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/4932316) is exactly what you need. The key here is `fig.canvas.draw()` and then use `get_text()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify tick label text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text)

Comment: @Bazingaa not really, I am specifically asking how to access the properties of that object. It's way broader than simply changing the text and it allows me a great degree of flexibility in what I can do with the labels.

Comment: Ok, so IOBE's comment solves your problem

Comment: I am trying to generalize it right now =). I believe it does

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest @Bazingaa since we are here. Could you also help me out with understanding what are the rows in `labels`? I posted a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378410/matplotlib-xticks-extracting-the-labels-object-what-are-the-elements-in-ther) about it

Comment: @Gio: If I understood your question on "rows" correctly, the rows you see in the image you posted are the attributes of your labels objects. You can change their values using `get` and `set` like I did in my answer below for changing the colors

Comment: @Bazingaa what I do not understand is why if I have `N` ticks and `N` labels I have `2*N` rows

Comment: @Gio: I saw that IOBE answered your comment on a different post.

Comment: @Bazingaa yup, that's solved as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in an alternative solution where you can choose which specific ticks you want to color. Here I have to loop from `[1:-1]` because the first and the last ticks do not appear on the graph here but they appear in the `labels`

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(134)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y=np.random.normal(0, 1, (8, 1))
plt.scatter(x, y)

fig.canvas.draw()
xticks = ax.get_xticklabels()

target_ticks = [1, 3, 6, len(xticks)-2]

for i, lab in enumerate(xticks[1:-1]):
    if i+1 in target_ticks:
        lab.set_color('r')
```

[image]