# Selectively remove ticklabels (major and/or minor) from logarithmic axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Consider the following example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.set_xlim([2e-2, 2e-1])
ax.set_ylim([2e+1, 2e+3])

ax.plot([0.02, 0.1, 0.2], [20, 1000, 2000])

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Now, I wish to selectively remove/change tick-labels from the x-axis, insofar to keep only `['0.02', '0.10', '0.20']`, while keeping the tick-markers. How do I do this?

**Edit**

The strategy that I originally wanted to follow seems to suffer from a bug. I considered this

```py
fig.canvas.draw()

labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xticklabels()]

# ...

ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

But on my mac it only prints

```
>>> print(labels)
['', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can rotate the x-labels 90 degrees.  https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html

Comment: @swatchai Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I agree that that is a good solution. I'm still keen though on my objective. Also, I've tried quite a bit to do this, but I must admit that I'm hopelessly confused on how to control major/minor ticklabels.

Comment: if you want to stick to your method and have ticks at some specific location, you need to turn on the minor ticks as `ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True)` and before this, put `fig.canvas.draw()` in your code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/4932316). It might help

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks. However, even with `fig.canvas.draw()` and `ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True)` or `ax.get_xaxis().get_majorticklabels()` or `ax.get_xaxis().get_minorticklabels()` I get lists of empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to have ticks at multiples of 1 and 2 of integer powers of the logarithmic base (10). This can be done with a `matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(subs=(1,2,))`. You may then use a `NullLocator()` to turn minor labels off.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.set_xlim([2e-2, 2e-1])
ax.set_ylim([2e+1, 2e+3])

ax.plot([0.02, 0.1, 0.2], [20, 1000, 2000])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(subs=(1,2,)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very nice. Just out of curiosity, why is the output of e.g. `print([item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xaxis().get_minorticklabels()])` just `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`?

Comment: The ticklabels are determined at draw time, not before (because the labels are not known before the axes gets drawn). You can draw it manually it you want, putting `fig.canvas.draw()` before your print statement.

Comment: I'm talking about your original code here. In the code from this answer, you will of course still get the `['', '', '', '']` because the minor labels are set to empty strings via the `NullFormatter`.

Comment: I was too ;) Also there I only get lists of empty strings.

Comment: In your original code when adding `fig.canvas.draw(); print([item.get_text() for item in ax.get_xaxis().get_minorticklabels()])`, the output is `['0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.01', '0.02', '0.03', '0.04', '0.05', '0.06', '0.07', '0.08', '0.09', '0.20', '0.30', '0.40', '0.50',
 '0.60', '0.70', '0.80', '0.90', '2.00', '3.00', '4.00', '5.00', '6.00', '7.00', '8.00', '9.00', '20.00', '30.00', '40.00', '50.00', '60.00', '70.00', '80.00',
'90.00']`

Comment: Then it might be a bug, because I only get lists of empty strings, also with your code.

Comment: A bug in which version? I tried with matplotlib 2.2.2, 3.0.2, current development version (will soon be 3.1.0) and the output is the same. In version 2.0.2 the labels are different, but not all empty either.

Comment: I used 3.0.3. See [this post](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13968).