# customize matplotlib ticklabels individually

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please consider the following example in which I want to change the `weight` of label "C" to `bold`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': [3, 5, 7, 4, 5]},
                  index=list('ABCDE'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.barh(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Many examples I've seen (e.g., `tick_params` and `set_yticklabels`) change all ticklabels or simply replace a label [without formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text).

Is there a way to customize it individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do so:

- Traverse through the default tick-labels,
- Modify the required label to be **bold faced**,
- Reassign the tick-labels.

---

```
from matplotlib import rc
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc('text', usetex=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': [3, 5, 7, 4, 5]},
                  index=list('ABCDE'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.barh(ax=ax)

fig.canvas.draw()
new_labels = []
to_modify = 'C'

for lab in ax.get_yticklabels():
    txt = lab.get_text()
    if txt == to_modify:
        new_labels.append(r'$\textbf{%s}$' %txt) # append bold face text
    else:    
        new_labels.append(txt) # append normal text

ax.set_yticklabels(new_labels)
```

[image]

**Alternative as suggested by [ImportanceOfBeingEarnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)** : `set_fontweight` only works if not using latex (TeX rendering).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.barh(ax=ax)

to_modify = 'C'

for lab in ax.get_yticklabels():
    if lab.get_text() == to_modify:
      lab.set_fontweight('bold')
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_fontweight

Comment: Thx man. This is indeed a way to do that! But using latex may have some limit. For example, in case I need to change fontsize etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks for the link. I must upgrade to 3+ soon. Can't do it at the moment due to some reasons.

Comment: @steven : You can still change the fontsize even with TeX turned on

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sorry I'm not following. Is there a way to do it without using `fig.canvas.draw()`?

Comment: @steven : Check my edited answer based on IOBE suggestion. I tried it on Google CoLab and it worked without using `fig.canvas.draw()`

Comment: Maybe one should note that `set_fontweight` only works if ***not*** using latex. Also important to note: `fig.canvas.draw()` is not needed in this case where `df.plot.bar` is used, but in general it is correct, e.g. if using `plt.barh` instead, it would be necessary.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Thanks again. Added the important words to the answer.

Comment: I tried to set the weight with an int (0, 1000) based on the doc but i didn't see anything when setting it to 550, but it suddenly becomes obviously bold when setting to 560, and then has no visual change after than even set to 1000. Am I missing something?

Comment: it seems like [not all font supports all weight](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14801#event-2486487150)

Comment: I'm not sure why but the .get_text() comes back empty when running the python script. When I debug the script and step thru it it DOES return a string.