# How do you change the x-axis scale/ticks in a bar chart with time values in the x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time                                  Instances
00:32:00                              1
00:35:00                              1
00:51:00                              1
01:51:00                              1
04:08:00                              1
05:13:00                              1
05:14:00                              1
05:34:00                              1
05:51:00                              1
07:36:00                              1
07:53:00                              1
08:20:00                              1
09:34:00                              1
10:01:00                              1
10:18:00                              1
10:38:00                              1
10:51:00                              1
11:15:00                              1
12:14:00                              1
13:16:00                              1
13:28:00                              1
13:51:00                              1
15:56:00                              1
16:22:00                              1
16:35:00                              1
17:19:00                              1
```

I want to plot this but I would like the "ticks" on the x-axis to be 00:00:00,04:00:00,08:00:00,12:00:00,16:00:00,20:00:00,23:59:00. So I started out with this code('t' is the name of my data frame).

EDIT: Adding part of code that loads data in.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import random
import datetime
df=pd.read_csv(path)
df['Time']= pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df=df.sort_values("Time")
df.Time = df.Time.map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0))
df['Time'] =df['Time'].dt.time
t=df['Time'].value_counts().reset_index()
t.columns=['Time','Instances']
t=t.sort_values("Time")
ax = t.plot(x='Time',y='Instances',kind='bar', title ="Number of Instances By Time of Day", figsize=(20, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticks([datetime.time(0,0,0,0),datetime.time(4,0,0,0),datetime.time(8,0,0,0),datetime.time(12,0,0,0),datetime.time(16,0,0,0),datetime.time(20,0,0,0),datetime.time(23,59,0,0)])
ax.set_xticklabels([datetime.time(0,0,0,0),datetime.time(4,0,0,0),datetime.time(8,0,0,0),datetime.time(12,0,0,0),datetime.time(16,0,0,0),datetime.time(20,0,0,0),datetime.time(23,59,0,0)])
```

When I run this code, however, I get a blank graph.
[image]

Looking to fix this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide also the data loading (e.g. csv/excel reading and datetime conversion if it has been done)

Comment: @Nikaido added that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with aliasing as I don't see what 't' is aliased as?.

```
ax = t.plot(x='Time',y='Instances',kind='bar', title ="Number of Instances By Time of Day", figsize=(20, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
```

Instead try

```
ax = plt.plot(x='Time',y='Instances',kind='bar', title ="Number of Instances By Time of Day", figsize=(20, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
```

Comment: When I did plt.plot(x=t['Time'],y=t['Instances'],kind='bar',title='Number of Instances By Time of Day',figsize=(20,10),legend=True,fontsize=12) I got the error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'" on the set_xticks line of code.

Comment: So why you are using x=t[time] ? What is the use of putting it in the list

Comment: That's not where I am getting the error. The error is on the next line of code when I do ax.set_xticks([datetime.time(0,0,0,0),datetime.time(4,0,0,0),datetime.time(8,0,0,0),datetime.time(12,0,0,0),datetime.time(16,0,0,0),datetime.time(20,0,0,0),datetime.time(23,59,0,0)]). Even if I do not do t['Time'] I still get that same error.

Comment: One last thing you can try is first try to run it by changing ax = t.plot(x='Time',y='Instances',kind='bar', title ="Number of Instances By Time of Day", figsize=(20, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12).  To.     ax.plot(x='Time',y='Instances',kind='bar', title ="Number of Instances By Time of Day", figsize=(20, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12).   And see weather u are getting tick or not

Comment: Because i dont find anything wrong in your code and i have worked on using ticks. So thats why saying you you to do so dude.

Comment: When I try to do just ax.plot... I get the error: NameError: name 'ax' is not defined.

Comment: Have a look at this answerhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/11250884/12777391

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207791/discussion-between-code-wizard-and-ajhello).