# How to replace label values of y axis by an equivalent number in figure produced by Python-matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The following figure is produced by python-matplotlib, I want to realize to two things:
1.Replace the original value of y axis by a new equivalent number, for example, -2*1e-5 replaced by -20*1e-6;
2.Change the font, font size and font style of the exponent.
P.s. The curve consists of many data points stored in a txt file(using ‘with open()’ syntax to get these data).

[image: Figure plotted by matplotlib]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to read, but… if the unit of height is μm, then `plot(x, 10**6*y) ; plt.ylabel("Height (pm)")` could be everything that's really needed.  On the other hand, you may have a reason for the use of a specific unit.

Comment: sounds like you want to change the tick labels - have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text