# Subsetting columns and counting the 1's (TURF analysis?)

Tags: python, pandas, subset, upsetplot

The aim is to count the corresponding 1's in the rows of each subset (>2) of columns:

```
    0   2   4
0   0   1   0
1   1   1   1
2   1   0   0
3   1   1   0
4   1   0   0
... ... ... ...
```

In above example we would have 4 subsets. Then the idea is to summarize these counts in a bar plot where each bar is labelled according the subset.

The aim is to make an UpSet plot

[image: UpSet plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for an [UpSetPlot](https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
# pip install upsetplot
import upsetplot

upsetplot.plot(df.astype(bool).value_counts())
```

Output:

[image]

With all combinations

```
upsetplot.plot(df.astype(bool).value_counts()
                 .reindex(product([True, False], repeat=3), fill_value=0)
              )
```

[image]

##### older answer

It looks like you might want something like:

```
df.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Or, by column name for `1` values:

```
(df.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='cols')
   .query('value == 1')
   .groupby('index')['cols'].agg(frozenset)
   .value_counts().plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Second plot is close, but subset needs to be >2 and is missing subsets 2,4 and 0,4

Comment: There is no case with 2/4, so you want 0?

Comment: The intersection size is not yet correct, for example, [0, 4] has one row in common, so intersection size is 1. [0, 2, 4] has intersection size 1.

Comment: Please provide a clear example, with a mockup graph, what you want is currently unclear. On my graph, there is a count of 1 for 0,2,4

Comment: Is there a way to customize the plot? Increase figure size, add colors, etc.?

Comment: Yes of course, you can do anything you want. The underlying plot is made with matplotlib. I suggest you to read the documentation, give it a try and open a new question if needed.

Comment: do you know how to add punctuation to the numbers? If I set show_counts=True

Comment: Not sure you can do this natively, but your can [modify the tick labels after plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text)

Comment: Most matplotlib statements do not work with UpSet: 'UpSet' object has no attribute 'style'

Comment: @Sean you should use `dic = upsetplot.plot(df.astype(bool).value_counts())`, then each value of the `dic` is a [`matplotlib.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) object that you can modify.

Comment: What was the purpose of that reindex and product?

Comment: First run `product([True, False], repeat=3)` to see what it outputs (all combinations of True/False for 3 items). `reindex` ensures all combinations are present in the DataFrame's index.

Comment: I've tried everything, but can't seem to be able to add .2f style to the numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research can you open a new question with a minimal self-sufficient code to replicate your issue?

Comment: I've just posted a new question

Comment: Have you had the time to take a look at the question I posted?